Resolve hook not run for require
Given this resolve hook:
export async function resolve(specifier, context, nextResolve) {    
    const dir = dirname(path);
    if (/fs/.test(specifier)) specifier = join(dir, 'fake.js');

    return nextResolve(specifier, context);
};

Why is this hook not run when using CommonJS require to load dependencies? I.e. this fails:
const { readFileSync } = require('fs'); // Imported from the real fs module

while this works:
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'; // Imported from fake.js

I am aware that customization hooks are an ESM feature, but the documentation clearly indicates it should work for require as well (emphasis mine):

The resolve hook chain is responsible for telling Node.js where to
find and how to cache a given import statement or expression, or
require call.

The hook is properly registered using node:module#register and loaded at the start using the --import option.
To preemptively answer the question why I don't just stick with import instead of require: I encountered this with third-party dependencies that require a module I am trying to mock, so I have no control over how they do this. Specifically, I am trying to make a fs mock for testing.

Have you tried const readFileSync = require('fs') (without the brackets)? Or better yet, const fs = require('fs') and then utilize fs.readFileSync(...).

I don't see how that will help with the resolve hook not being run.

I'm assuming there is a silent error caused by the way fs is being loaded, which means the package never resolves. That would be my first guess on why resolve hook doesn't run when utilizing a const object definition with a require import. Unsure the issue if it's not that.

The import resolves, it just resolves to the actual fs package. Which it shouldn't, that's the whole point of the hook. FWIW, I've filed a bug report for this now: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/55878

The next guess would be that it's a sync issue if the package is loading and resolve is not triggered. The CommonJS is most likely running the resolve proc before the resolve has been loaded. I looked into it, and both do work as long as the resolve is defined before fs is loaded. You may be able to try to run your resolve at the script entry level to see if this is the case. Good luck!

I'm importing the resolve hook as a command line argument (node --import=./register.js index.cjs), so this really shouldn't be the case. To be extra sure, I wrapped the CommonJS in a ten second delay (setTimeout), which should be ample time for any race conditions to resolve. I'm still consistently seeing the same behavior. Your last comment sounds like you had some luck getting it to work - what exactly did you do?
